# To HOLD COURT en Español

Tags: expresiones

En inglés, la expresión TO HOLD COURT describe el acto de un rey o gobernante que hace acto de presencia en la corte real para presidir. Más comunmente se usa por analogia para describir a una persona que está siendo el centro de atención.

¿Existe una expresión analoga en español?

PRESIDIR pierde el uso popular, mientras que SER EL CENTRO DE ATENCION no tiene el mismo peso visual...

Answer (score 1):

La expresión legal es celebrar/conceder audiencia. Podría tener también el sentido que buscas de ser el centro de atención.

Answer (score 0):

A mí me gusta la expresión **tener presencia**, por ejemplo:

> —Andá a llamar a Juan. 
> —¿Y cómo lo puedo reconocer? 
> —Él **tiene presencia** en todos los grupos en los que está, es imposible confundirlo.

Comment: it may not be exactly the same but there is  an expression ''ser el ombligo del mundo''. I am not a native speaker but I think it means to be self-important or to feel egotistical or the centre of the universe. It would be nice if there was a more accurate expression offered also like the previous contributors'.

Comment: "Sentirse el ombligo del mundo" carries a negative connotation -- the person thinks or acts as if they are the center of the universe but they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Una expresión que se me ocurre es "llevarse todas las miradas".

- Dondequiera que esté, siempre se lleva todas las miradas. (He/She holds court wherever he/she is.)